# Clip Composable to Shape of Contents

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an icon that has a quarter circle shaped drawable in it. I'm using the Accompanist Placeholder library during the loading state, however the Placeholder is in the shape of a square with the shimmer rather than the quarter circle content.

I'm trying to figure out how I can clip the shape of the icon to the shape of the contents so that the composable will be a quarter circle shape and appear properly.

I tried making the placeholder color property transparent in hopes that it would show the underlying quarter circle and apply the shimmer to that, but it makes the whole composable transparent instead.

Here's how it looks with the placeholder applied:
[image]

And the shape I want it to be (no placeholder applied to the quarter circle, just color):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want the placeholder shape to be a quarter circle instead of a square. You can achieve this by using `Modifier.placeholder(shape = RoundedCornerShape(bottomEnd = 24.dp))`

Replace 24.dp with your square's size.